# How to stop slider when mouse hover?

Tags: jquery, hover, slider

How do I stop the slider when I hover on the slider images? I have used following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script> 
$('.testimonials-slider').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 800,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 1,
    slideMargin: 32,
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true
});
```

Comment: You need to wrap your bxSlider code within script tag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set the autoHover option to true e.g:

```
...
auto: true,
autoHover: true,
autoControls: true
...
```

See http://bxslider.com/options#autoHover for more info and other options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the autoHover: true option in script tag: